# JSONP decorator in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, jsonp, httpresponse, jsonresponse

The JSONP decorator allows a standard `application/json` response to be returned as a Javascript function defined in the `callback` parameter.

In this case I'm using JsonResponse (subclass of HttpResponse) and the `if` condition causes the function to return the original response instead of JSONP formatted one. I would say it's because the `simplejson` parser is not compatible with `HttpResponse` objects.

The question is how to make it compatible with `JsonResponse`?

JSON response `https://www.domain.com/data.json`:

{"doc": "546546545", "order": "98745", "nothing": "0.0"}

JSONP response `https://www.domain.com/data.json?callback=jQuery111305146260466426611_1448872734459`:

jQuery111305146260466426611_1448872734459({"doc": "546546545", "order": "98745", "nothing": "0.0"});

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from collections import OrderedDict
from polls.jsonp_decorator import json_response

@json_response
def sampledata(request):

    data = OrderedDict([('doc', '546546545'), ('order', '98745'), ('nothing', '0.0')])

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

jsonp_decorator.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import simplejson

def json_response(func):

    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(objects, HttpResponse): #here it returns objects
            return objects
        try:
            data = simplejson.dumps(objects)
            if 'callback' in request.REQUEST:
                # A jsonp response!
                data = '%s(%s);' % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)
                return HttpResponse(data, 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8')
        except:
            data = simplejson.dumps(str(objects))
        return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

Firstly, `isinstance` returns true for subclasses; so `isinstance(objects, HttpResponse)` is true if `objects` is a JsonResponse.

Secondly, JsonResponse is *already* serialized to JSON; there'd be no point calling `simplejson.dumps()` on it. If you want to use this decorator, you should return the plain dict from the view function.

Thirdly, you must **never ever ever** catch a bare except. Anything could be going wrong, and you'd never know - hence your uncertainty about where the problem is in this code. Catch only the exceptions you're expecting; in this case, a TypeError is raised if something is not serializable, so you should catch that.